# Clickable Image as Nav Bar Title in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I've looked through several threads on here that discuss:

1. Setting an image for title
2. Using a button for title

However, I'm trying to combine the two, i.e., clickable image (button) as title.

Unfortunately, while the below code compiles the image doesn't show when assigned as a button. Any suggestions?

```
func addNavBarImage() {
    let navController = navigationController!

    let button =  UIButton(type: .custom)
    var image = UIImage(named: "textLogo")
    image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
    let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

    let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - image!.size.width  / 2
    let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - image!.size.height / 2

    button.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    button.imageView?.image = image

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.logoTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = button
}
```

Comment: button.setImage(image ,forState:.normal) ??

Comment: I highly recommend against force unwrapping the navigationContoller! And wrapping it around a guard let of if let. Because as your code stands, if for whatever reason the navigationController is nil your app will crash.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation@OverD. I've updated my code to look similar to @Bliss 's suggestion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `UIImageView`, add it as titleView and add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIImageView`

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = UIImage.named("yourImage")
// do any settings to your imageView
let titleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(titlePressed))
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
self.navigationItem.titleView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
self.navigationItem.titleView?.addGestureRecognizer(titleTap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code for me.

```
let button =  UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage (named: "your_image"), for: .normal)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickOnButton), for: .touchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.titleView = button
```

Here you can see in last line button is directly set to the titleView of navigationItem which will add button at the center of navigation bar.

Action method for button is below:

```
@objc func clickOnButton(button: UIButton) {
    print("Title Tapped")
}
```